# How is it so fast (Algorithm or Logic behind it)

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know how does Oracle SQL Developer get the distinct count so fast as shown in below image, there is a popup which shows list of distinct values which are used to filter the data.I am interested in knowing method or logic used.[image]

Comment: I guess it's getting the values from the *retrieved* result, not from the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just saw you closed the question whose answer you guessed(which means u probably do not know the answer!) to be above. Don't see any reason why you closed it?

Answer (score 2):

Just speculating, it could use three approaches

- If the column is in a unique index, it can use the index to give you the unique values.
- Otherwise it can search through all the existing entries. It should be able to do about one million per second if the data is in memory.
- Or give you the cached query result based on using either of the previous approaches or some other which I haven't thought of.